# Longest palindromic substring missing an edge case

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, palindrome

This is code I have written using dynamic programming concepts.

```
bool ispalin(string s)
    {
        string s1=s;
        reverse(s.begin(),s.end());
        if(s1.compare(s)==0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    string longestPalindrome(string s) {
       int n = s.length();
        if(n==1)
            return s;
       
        vector<vector<int>> dp(n,vector<int>(n,0));
        pair<int,int>coor;
        for(int i =0;i<n;i++)
        {
            dp[i][i]=1;
            coor=make_pair(i,i);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            int j=i+1;
            if(j<n)
            {
                if(ispalin(s.substr(i,j)))
                   {
                       dp[i][j]=1;
                       coor=make_pair(i,j);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       dp[i][j]=0;
                   }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
            for(int j=2;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(i<j)
                {
                    if(s[i]==s[j] && dp[i+1][j-1]==1)
                    {
                        dp[i][j]=1;
                        coor=make_pair(i,j);
                    }
                    else
                        dp[i][j]=0;
                }
            }
       }
        return s.substr(coor.first,coor.second);
                   
    }
```

What I have tried to do is

1. first for loop is to fill the diagonal elements.
2. for loop is to fill elements for length 2 i.e - I check if that substring is palindrome if yes I make it 1 else 0.
3. Whenever I update a cell to 1 I store `coor` pair to those coordinates so that they always have the latest values where 1 was updated.

It does not work on cases "bb", "ccc" how am I missing this case in the code?

Comment: *how am I missing this case in the code?*-- [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: lol thanks for this @PaulMcKenzie didnt solve my issue but understood what you meant Ill try again

Comment: Yes, use the debugger and see where those failing test cases take a different path in the code than what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using **substr** function is not correct. First argument should be the starting index and the second argument is the length of string.

Your code must be failing for this string as well "abccbdf".

Change

```
if(ispalin(s.substr(i,j)))
```

to this

```
if(ispalin(s.substr(i,2)))
```

And, in last return statement, your "coor" have correct value, but "substr" second argument is incorrect.
Use this statement instead:

```
return s.substr(coor.first,coor.second-coor.first+1);
```

Comment: I made your changes and code still fails for cases "aaaa" o/p- "aaa" and "aaaaa" o/p- "aaa"

Comment: would be great if you could help me on how to solve this

Comment: nevermind I found the error I had to traverse update the cells diagonally in this :D